# Highcharts - Pie Chart change slice colors dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, charts, highcharts

The chart calls in JSON file that hold a string(color) and integer(count). I want to change the color of the each slice in a pie chart according to what the JSON file holds. So if the JSON file is `[["Green",1],["Red",44],["Yellow",30]]` I would like the the "Green" slice to have the color of green...etc. I've tried:

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        //colors: ['#739600', '#bb0826', '#fcc60A'],
        formatter: function () {
                if ('Green' === this.value) {
                    return '<span style="fill: #739600;">' + this.value + '</span>';
                } 
                else if ('Red' === this.value) {
                    return '<span style="fill: #bb0826;">' + this.value + '</span>';
                }
                else if ('Yellow' === this.value) {
                    return '<span style="fill: #fcc60A;">' + this.value + '</span>';
                }
            }, ...
```

It's not working how I expected. http://jsfiddle.net/LazerickL/bvaxmcLr/4/

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I had to restructure my JavaScript to call $.getJSON function. So, how would I proceed to implement the color slices for my latest code below? Thanks for any help!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'containter',      
        defaultSeriesType: 'pie',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 45
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: null                  
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false              
    },
    tooltip: {
    pointFormat:                    
    '{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
},

plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        //colors: ['#739600', '#bb0826', '#fcc60A'],
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        depth: 30, 
        showInLegend: true,         
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000',
            connectorColor: '#000000',
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.point.y;
            }
        }
    }
},
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Amount',
        data: []
    }]
}

$.getJSON("js/test.json", function (json) {
    options.series[0].data = json;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set your colors on your pies you'll need to update how you're pushing things into the data array to include the color of your pie. I accomplish this by adding a field to your data array but you could use an if statement like you had in the function if you prefer. 
Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bvaxmcLr/8/

Also, your placement of the formatter function is invalid. That formatter javascript only applies to data labels as far as I know.

The important change from your script is removing the formatter function and updating to this to push the color value onto each data point:

```
  var data={'d':[
        {'Status_Color':'Green', 'Corrective_Action_ID':3},
        {'Status_Color':'Red', 'Corrective_Action_ID':5},
        {'Status_Color':'Yellow', 'Corrective_Action_ID':10},
    ]};
     $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {
        var colorVal = '';
        if(value.Status_Color=='Green'){
            colorVal = '#739600';
        }
        if(value.Status_Color=='Red'){
            colorVal = '#bb0826';
        }
        if(value.Status_Color=='Yellow'){
            colorVal = '#fcc60A';
        }

        var temp = {name:value.Status_Color, color:colorVal, y:value.Corrective_Action_ID};
        options.series[0].data.push(temp);

    })
```

Here is the whole script:

$(function () {

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var options = {

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'pie',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 45
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: null
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y:.1f}</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {

            depth: 45,
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            showInLegend: true
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Amount',
        data: []
    }]

    }
    var data={'d':[
        {'Status_Color':'Green', 'Corrective_Action_ID':3},
        {'Status_Color':'Red', 'Corrective_Action_ID':5},
        {'Status_Color':'Yellow', 'Corrective_Action_ID':10},
    ]};
     $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {
        var colorVal = '';
        if(value.Status_Color=='Green'){
            colorVal = '#739600';
        }
        if(value.Status_Color=='Red'){
            colorVal = '#bb0826';
        }
        if(value.Status_Color=='Yellow'){
            colorVal = '#fcc60A';
        }

        var temp = {name:value.Status_Color, color:colorVal, y:value.Corrective_Action_ID};
        options.series[0].data.push(temp);

    })

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

});
```

});

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. This will not work in my situation because I can't change my JSON file format. It has to be in the format of what I posted above: [["Green",1],["Red",44],["Yellow",30]]. I'm getting the data form MS SQL database, I can't add any other objects to the JSON file. Any other suggestions? Thank you all for the help!

Comment: @Megatron You don't have to change the data. You can use the same if statement structure you had in your function. I've updated my answer and the JS Fiddle with a different version (http://jsfiddle.net/bvaxmcLr/8/). Also, you could pass the string directly to highcharts. It will evaluate the color string for you if you are happy with the hex values they use. Example of using the string colors here (http://jsfiddle.net/bvaxmcLr/9/)

Comment: That worked perfect, thanks a lot! I had addition question that I made in my edit above. I have to format my JavaScript a bit for the $.getJSON function, how would I implement the color with my new Javascript? Thanks!

Comment: Generally you should do the same thing as before. Just move it into your new function.Get the data, build each data row individually with x/y/color, push to array. Right now you're just pushing the raw JSON and you need to apply the formatting. Basically move the if statement to your getJson function,